# How can I originate emails to recipients NOT listed in email headers (using EWS or office-js, or maybe emulating SMTP using the MS stack)?

Tags: outlook, office-js, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

My add-in does "forensic mailing" (all email recipients receive imperceptibly different steganographic mail body content) for the purpose of identifying policy infractions (e.g. "leaks").  e.g. This means that when an email is sent:-

```
From: Person A
To: person B 
Cc: person C
Bcc: person D
```

that 4 different individual emails are generated (the original in the senders "Sent" folder, plus a new version for each of the 3 recipients = 4 total).

Using SMTP, it's a simple matter to set the appropriate headers, and use "RCPT TO" 3 times to send each mail.

What would be the Office-JS or EWS or any other available equivalent way to originate my emails using "Microsoft Techniques" ?  Is it possible to perform "SMTP over EWS" or similar, so I can re-use my existing (Linux) codebase ?

Is there some way to specify a "Bcc" recipient, along with the "To:" and "Cc:" email headers, and then transmit the mail to that Bcc recipient *only*, to emulate SMTP ?

Comment: This question appears to be on-topic, which is great. You don't need to put a disclaimer about only wanting help from people you deem qualified (in fact this content is just a distraction and therefore is likely to be edited out, as I have done with this question). Just ask good, on-topic questions and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unlike SMTP, EWS, Extended MAPI, and Outlook Object Model won't let you specify different recipients than those that will actually receive the message.

SMTP is your best and only option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook web add-ins you need to use `OfficeJS` methods and properties to set up recipients:

```
var item;

Office.initialize = function () {
    item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    // Checks for the DOM to load using the jQuery ready function.
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // After the DOM is loaded, app-specific code can run.
        // Set recipients of the composed item.
        setRecipients();
    });
}

// Set the display name and email addresses of the recipients of 
// the composed item.
function setRecipients() {
    // Local objects to point to recipients of either
    // the appointment or message that is being composed.
    // bccRecipients applies to only messages, not appointments.
    var toRecipients, ccRecipients, bccRecipients;

    // Verify if the composed item is an appointment or message.
    if (item.itemType == Office.MailboxEnums.ItemType.Appointment) {
        toRecipients = item.requiredAttendees;
        ccRecipients = item.optionalAttendees;
    }
    else {
        toRecipients = item.to;
        ccRecipients = item.cc;
        bccRecipients = item.bcc;
    }
    
    // Use asynchronous method setAsync to set each type of recipients
    // of the composed item. Each time, this example passes a set of
    // names and email addresses to set, and an anonymous 
    // callback function that doesn't take any parameters. 
    toRecipients.setAsync(
        [{
            "displayName":"Graham Durkin", 
            "emailAddress":"graham@contoso.com"
         },
         {
            "displayName" : "Donnie Weinberg",
            "emailAddress" : "donnie@contoso.com"
         }],
        function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                write(asyncResult.error.message);
            }
            else {
                // Async call to set to-recipients of the item completed.

            }    
    }); // End to setAsync.


    // Set any cc-recipients.
    ccRecipients.setAsync(
        [{
             "displayName":"Perry Horning", 
             "emailAddress":"perry@contoso.com"
         },
         {
             "displayName" : "Guy Montenegro",
             "emailAddress" : "guy@contoso.com"
         }],
        function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                write(asyncResult.error.message);
            }
            else {
                // Async call to set cc-recipients of the item completed.
            }
    }); // End cc setAsync.


    // If the item has the bcc field, i.e., item is message,
    // set bcc-recipients.
    if (bccRecipients) {
        bccRecipients.setAsync(
            [{
                 "displayName":"Lewis Cate", 
                 "emailAddress":"lewis@contoso.com"
             },
             {
                 "displayName" : "Francisco Stitt",
                 "emailAddress" : "francisco@contoso.com"
             }],
            function (asyncResult) {
                if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                    write(asyncResult.error.message);
                }
                else {
                    // Async call to set bcc-recipients of the item completed.
                    // Do whatever appropriate for your scenario.
                }
        }); // End bcc setAsync.
    }
}

// Writes to a div with id='message' on the page.
function write(message){
    document.getElementById('message').innerText += message; 
}
```

When calling `setAsync`, provide an array as input argument for the recipients parameter, in one of the following formats.

- An array of strings that are SMTP addresses.
- An array of dictionaries, each containing a display name and email address, as shown in the following code sample.
- An array of `EmailAddressDetails` objects, similar to the one returned by the `getAsync` method.

If you do not want to overwrite any existing recipients in an appointment or message, instead of using `Recipients.setAsync`, you can use the `Recipients.addAsync` asynchronous method to append recipients. `addAsync` works similarly as `setAsync` in that it requires a recipients input argument. You can optionally provide a callback method, and any arguments for the callback using the `asyncContext` parameter. You can then check the status, result, and any error of the asynchronous `addAsync` call by using the `asyncResult` output parameter of the callback method.

Read more about that in the [Get, set, or add recipients when composing an appointment or message in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/get-set-or-add-recipients) article.

Comment: Nice answer, but it's not addressing the question whatsoever - the word NOT was in capitals for a reason.

Comment: Outlook (nor Exchange) doesn't allow doing so. The supported way of setting recipients is posted.